# How to theming and deploy custom blocks which created in admin UI?

Tags: 7, theming, blocks, features, deployment

I've created some custom blocks in my development environment and export them with `Features` + `FE Block` with given machine names. And then deploy and enable them in my staging environment.

Just like the sample below, the blocks with same machine name have different block ids in different environments, but I want the `guide` block has a special layout than other blocks.

```
development
    block-block-1 (guide)
    block-block-2 (case_links)

staging
    block-block-1 (case_links)
    block-block-2 (guide)
```

Because in different environments the `guide` block has different `block_id`, I can't just use the block id as the identifier to apply these css rules.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom classes or id's to your blocks. If you don't feel to code it yourself your best bet would be to use the [Block class module](http://drupal.org/project/block_class), and perhaps also along with the [Block Class Styles module](http://drupal.org/project/block_class_styles) which provides custom templates for your blocks.

--update--

The new version ([7.x-2.0](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/block_class-7.x-2.0.tar.gz)) of [Block Class](http://drupal.org/project/block_class_styles) module has just changed it database structure, removed the `block_class` table and add a field `css_class` into `block` table. The current version of [Block Class Styles module](http://drupal.org/project/block_class_styles) work well with Block Class 7.x-1.2.

Comment: Thanks, just follow your answer, I find that the `Block class module` has just release a new version 7.x-2.0 in which changed the database table structure (removed `block_class` table, add a `css_class` field in `block` table), so I can use FE Blocks exports blocks' css classes. But the newest version of Block Class Styles module doesn't work well with the 7.x-2.0 without any code change. I modify the code, and it just work OK now.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Glad to know it worked out for you.